# Change excel column width using StreamWriter

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need help in this code.

I'm working on code to export data-table data to an excel sheet using `StreamWriter`, every thing is good but i want to change the excel columns width for each column in the excel, i only can change the width for all columns at once.

this is the code for columns width :

```
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""100""/>")
```

is there a way to change columns (0) width = 20 and columns (1) width = 18
and so on ?
or make it auto-fit ??

thank you.

this is my code :

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class ExportToExcelClr
Public Sub ExportToExcel(datatable As DataTable, GV As DataGridView, filename As String, Optional OpenDialog As Boolean = False, Optional SameColumnsWidth As Boolean = True)
    Dim FlNm As String = ""
    Dim sv As New SaveFileDialog
    sv.FileName = filename
    sv.Filter = "|*.xls"
    If sv.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
    FlNm = sv.FileName
    Dim fs As New StreamWriter(FlNm, False)
    With fs
        .WriteLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?>")
        .WriteLine("<?mso-application progid=""Excel.Sheet""?>")
        .WriteLine("<Workbook xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"">")
        .WriteLine("  <Styles>")
        .WriteLine("  <Style ss:ID=""hdr"">")
        .WriteLine("  <Alignment ss:Horizontal=""Center""/>")
        .WriteLine("  <Borders>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Left"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Right"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Top"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("  </Borders>")
        .WriteLine("  <Font ss:FontName=""Droid Arabic Kufi"" ss:Size=""8"" ss:Bold=""1""/>") 'SET FONT
        .WriteLine("  </Style>")
        .WriteLine("  <Style ss:ID=""ksg"">")
        .WriteLine("  <Alignment ss:Vertical=""Bottom""/>")
        .WriteLine("  <Borders/>")
        .WriteLine("  <Font ss:FontName=""Arial""/>") 'SET FONT
        .WriteLine("  </Style>")
        .WriteLine("  <Style ss:ID=""isi"">")
        .WriteLine("  <Borders>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Bottom"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Left"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Right"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("    <Border ss:Position=""Top"" ss:LineStyle=""Continuous"" ss:Weight=""1""/>")
        .WriteLine("  </Borders>")
        .WriteLine("  <Font ss:FontName=""Arial"" ss:Size=""11""/>")
        .WriteLine("  </Style>")
        .WriteLine("  </Styles>")
        .WriteLine("  <Worksheet ss:Name=""sheet1"">")
        .WriteLine("  <Table>")


        'If SameColumnsWidth Then
        'For i = 0 To GV.ColumnCount - 1
        .WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""100""/>")
            'Next
            'End If

            .WriteLine("  <Row ss:StyleID=""ksg"">")

        For i As Integer = 0 To GV.ColumnCount - 1
            Application.DoEvents()
            .WriteLine("  <Cell ss:StyleID=""hdr"">")
            .WriteLine("    <Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</Data>", GV.Columns.Item(i).HeaderText)
            .WriteLine("  </Cell>")
        Next


        .WriteLine("  </Row>")
        For intRow As Integer = 0 To datatable.Rows.Count - 1
            Application.DoEvents()
            .WriteLine("  <Row ss:StyleID=""ksg"" ss:utoFitHeight =""0"">")
            For intCol As Integer = 0 To datatable.Columns.Count - 1
                Application.DoEvents()
                .WriteLine("  <Cell ss:StyleID=""isi"">")
                .WriteLine("  <Data ss:Type=""String"">{0}</Data>", GV.Item(intCol, intRow).Value.ToString)
                .WriteLine("  </Cell>")
            Next
            .WriteLine("  </Row>")
        Next
        .WriteLine("  </Table>")
        .WriteLine("  </Worksheet>")
        .WriteLine("</Workbook>")
        .Close()
        If OpenDialog Then
            Dim msg1
            msg1 = MsgBox("تم الاستخراج ... هل تريد فتح الملف ؟", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Export")
            If msg1 = vbNo Then Exit Sub
            Process.Start(FlNm)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Sub DataGridView_COLORE_FOR_ME(ByVal DataGridViewXT As Object)
    Try
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        DataGridViewXT.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
        DataGridViewXT.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192)
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRight + MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxRtlReading, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this attribute (AutoFitWidth) is specified as True ("1"), it means that this column should be autosized for numeric and date values only. We do not autofit textual values.

If both ss:Width and ss:AutoFitWidth exist, the behavior is as follows:

```
ss:AutoFitWidth="1" and ss:Width is unspecified: Autofit the column width to fit the content.
ss:AutoFitWidth="1" and ss:Width is specified: Set the column to the specified width and only autofit if the size of the content is larger than the specified width.
ss:AutoFitWidth="0" and ss:Width is unspecified: Use the default column width.
ss:AutoFitWidth="0" and ss:Width is specified: Use the specified width.
```

Taken from here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/789892/How-to-set-autosize-the-cell-of-excell-sheet-when

Therefore your line would change from:

```
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""100""/>")
```

to either

```
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:AutoFitWidth=""1"" ss:Width=""20""/>")
```

or

```
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:AutoFitWidth=""1""/>")
```

The columns are ordered sequentially in the output file, so you could put them in as:

```
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""8""/>")
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""16""/>")
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""24""/>")
.WriteLine("  <Column ss:Width=""11""/>")
```

or

```
For i As Integer = 0 To GV.ColumnCount - 1
    .WriteLine("  <Column ss:AutoFitWidth=""1""/>")
Next
```

I would first create the file you want in Excel.  Save it as XML and view the XML in Google Chrome or IE.  This will show you what the xml should look like.

Comment: @Rabeea qabaha did my answer help you?